# OpenGL GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT

Tags: c++, opengl, maya

Before reading all this and getting lost my main question is how to unpack a single array of pixles and explaining how open gl is reading this data. (my background is not in c++ but mostly python)

your help is greatly appreciated.

im using maya(3d program) which has a class of MImage to get the pixel data of an image.
the return result is a single array with every 4 items are RGBA
this is what i need to unpack

```
pixels = [255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255] //two yellow pixels and it keeps going with this pattern
```

the following code creates a 256 x 256 image with 4 channels

```
unsigned int size = 256;
unsigned int depth = 4;

float color[3] = {1, 1, 0};

unsigned char *pixels = new unsigned char[size * size * depth];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i += depth){
    MScriptUtil::setUcharArray(pixels, i+0, (int)floorf(color[0] * 255.0f + 0.5f));
    MScriptUtil::setUcharArray(pixels, i+1, (int)floorf(color[1] * 255.0f + 0.5f));
    MScriptUtil::setUcharArray(pixels, i+2, (int)floorf(color[2] * 255.0f + 0.5f));
    pixels[i + 3] = 255;
    }
```

looking into this issue i came across this snippet (which create a checker pattern)which with the last block of code does work and show up with what im trying to do

```
static GLubyte checkImage[256][256][4];

int i, j, c;

for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
        c = ((((i&0x8)==0)^((j&0x8))==0))*255;
        checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) c;
        checkImage[i][j][3] = (GLubyte) 255;
    }
}
```

this array becomes (instead of 256x256 i made it 2x2)

```
[[[255, 255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255, 255]], [[255, 255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255, 255]]]// so on and so forth
```

with this i set the GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT to 1 and everything works

i just cant figure out how gl is reading arrays and how to tell it

for proof of code heres what i got

```
glDisable ( GL_LIGHTING );
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


glGenTextures(1, &glTextureObject);

// set the current texture to the one just created
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureObject);

// repeat the texture in both directions
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

// use bi-linear filtering on the texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);

// load the texture data into the graphics hardware.
glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Comment: Your loop only writes data for 256 bytes (64 pixels), since `size` is the upper limit of the loop counter.

Comment: Wowww I've been moving so much around that I must've missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` value should not come into play here. The default value is 4. Since you have 4 bytes per pixel when using RGBA values, the size of a row is always a multiple of 4.

The value only needs to be changed if the amount of data per row is not a multiple of 4. For example, if you have RGB data, with 3 bytes per pixel, you have to change it to 1, unless the rows are actually aligned to 4 byte multiples with extra padding.

The real problem I see in your code is the loop:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i += depth){
    MScriptUtil::setUcharArray(pixels, i+0, (int)floorf(color[0] * 255.0f + 0.5f));
    MScriptUtil::setUcharArray(pixels, i+1, (int)floorf(color[1] * 255.0f + 0.5f));
    MScriptUtil::setUcharArray(pixels, i+2, (int)floorf(color[2] * 255.0f + 0.5f));
    pixels[i + 3] = 255;
}
```

Since `size` is 256, this will only fill the first 256 bytes (corresponding to 64 pixels) with data. To match the definitions and the rest of your code, this loop should be:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size * size * depth; i += depth) {
```