# Calculating texture coordinates from a heightmap

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am currently building a height map terrain generator using OpenGL. It's a simple program that loads a height map image, iterates over the image data and generates vertices, indices and normals. At its current state it can render a height map with a single colour based on the normals.

[image]

My problem is generating correct UV coordinates for the diffuse map. It just comes out wrong:

[image]

This is the diffuse map I am trying to load:

[image]

Here is what I currently have:

**Generate Vertices, Normals and Indices**

```
// Generate Vertices and texture coordinates
    for (int row = 0; row <= this->imageHeight; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column <= this->imageWidth; column++)
        {
            float x = (float)column / (float)this->imageWidth;
            float y = (float)row / (float)this->imageHeight;

            float pixel = this->imageData[this->imageWidth * row + column];

            float z;
            if (row == this->imageHeight || column == this->imageWidth || row == 0 || column == 0)
            {
                z = 0.0f;
            }
            else
            {
                z = float(pixel / 256.0)*this->scale; 
            }

            MeshV3 mesh;
            mesh.position = glm::vec3(x, y, z);
            mesh.normal = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            mesh.texture = glm::vec2(x, y);

            this->mesh.push_back(mesh);

        }
    }

// Generate indices
    for (int row = 0; row < this->imageHeight; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < this->imageWidth; column++)
        {
            int row1 = row * (this->imageWidth + 1);
            int row2 = (row + 1) * (this->imageWidth + 1);

            // triangle 1
            this->indices.push_back(glm::uvec3(row1 + column, row1 + column + 1, row2 + column + 1));

            // triangle 2
            this->indices.push_back(glm::uvec3(row1 + column, row2 + column + 1, row2 + column));
        }
    }

// Generate normals
    for (int i = 0; i < this->indices.size(); i++)
    {
        glm::vec3 v1 = this->mesh[this->indices[i].x].position;
        glm::vec3 v2 = this->mesh[this->indices[i].y].position;
        glm::vec3 v3 = this->mesh[this->indices[i].z].position;

        glm::vec3 edge1 = v1 - v2;
        glm::vec3 edge2 = v1 - v3;
        glm::vec3 normal = glm::normalize(glm::cross(edge1, edge2));

        this->mesh[this->indices[i].x].normal += normal;
        this->mesh[this->indices[i].y].normal += normal;
        this->mesh[this->indices[i].z].normal += normal;
    }
```

I load the diffuse map with the following method

```
void Terrein::getDIffuseMap()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &this->texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texture); // all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    int width, height, nrChannels;

    std::string path = "assets/diffuse.jpg";
    this->diffuseData = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (this->diffuseData)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this->diffuseData);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load diffuse texture" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what might be wrong here. Is there an issue with how I am loading the image? Or am I not calculating the texture coordinates coorectly? Please let me know if there is anything else I should provide. I have been stuck at this for a few days now. Thanks!

Comment: Not your problem, but your calculation of `float pixel` probably accesses outside the bounds of `imageData`.  Since `pixel` is only used in the `else` part of the following `if`, move `pixel` into the body of the `else`.

Comment: where are your shaders?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you, I was getting an out of bounds error on the imageData. A stupid mistake on my part, and it fixed after taking your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of an image is aligned to 4 bytes.

This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4.

Since the image has 3 color channels (`GL_RGB`), and is tightly packed the size of a row of the image may not be aligned to 4 bytes.

When a RGB image with 3 color channels is loaded to a texture object, then [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) has to be set to 1:

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
             GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this->diffuseData);
```

The diffuse image in the question has a dimension of 390x390. So each row of the image has a size of `390 * 3 = 1170` bytes.
Since 1170 is not divisible by 4 (`1170 / 4 = 292,5`), the start of a row is not aligned to 4 bytes.

Related question: [Failing to map a simple unsigned byte rgb texture to a quad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202452/failing-to-map-a-simple-unsigned-byte-rgb-texture-to-a-quad/46203044#46203044)

Comment: Thank you! This completely resolved the issue and I learned something new. So in the future, I should use a texture image that is a divisible of 4. I updated the question with the working solution.

Comment: @AaronZaman You're welcome. If you use RGBA images, then this won't be an issue, because the size of each pixel is 4 and thus the length of each row is divisible by 4.

Comment: I actually thought about using RGBA, but then I stopped doing it as I thought I wouldn't need an alpha pass. But I do.

Comment: @AaronZaman Of course it needs some more memory, but there is nothing different in handling, if the alpha channel is 255 respectively 1.0.